# Identifying the components in a English sentence that do not make sense

Tags: artificial-intelligence, nlp, machine-learning, nltk, information-retrieval

I'm wondering is there an algorithm or a library which helps me identify the components in an English which has no meaning? e.g., **very serious** grammar error? If so, could you explain how it works, because I would really like to implement that or use that for my own projects.

Here's a random example:

In the sentence: "I closed so etc page hello the door."

As a human, we can quickly identify that [so etc page hello] does not make any sense. Is it possible for a machine to point out that the string does not make any sense and also contains grammar errors?

If there's such a solution, how precise can that be? Is it possible, for example, given a clip of an English sentence, the algorithm returns a measure, indicating how meaningful, or correct that clip is? Thank you very much!

PS: I've looked at CMU's link grammar as well as the NLTK library. But still I'm not sure how to use for example link grammar parser to do what I would like to do as the if the parser doesn't accept the sentence, I don't know how to tweak it to tell me which part it is not right.. and I'm not sure whether NLTK supported that.

Another thought I had towards solving the problem is to look at the frequencies of the word combination. Since I'm currently interested in correcting very serious errors only. If I define the "serious error" to be the cases where words in a clip of a sentence are rarely used together, i.e., the frequency of the combo should be much lower than those of the other combos in the sentence.

For instance, in the above example: [so etc page hello] these four words really seldom occur together. One intuition of my idea comes from when I type such combo in Google, no related results jump out. So is there any library that provides me such frequency information like Google does? Such frequencies may give a good hint on the correctness of the word combo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that what you are looking for is a [language model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_model). A language model assigns a probability to each sentence of `k` words appearing in your language. The simplest kind of language models are n-grams models: given the first `i` words of your sentence, the probability of observing the `i+1`th word only depends on the `n-1` previous words.

For example, for a bigram model (`n=2`), the probability of the sentence `w1 w2 ... wk` is equal to

```
P(w1 ... wk) = P(w1) P(w2 | w1) ... P(wk | w(k-1)).
```

To compute the probabilities `P(wi | w(i-1))`, you just have to count the number of occurrence of the bigram `w(i-1) wi` and  of the word `w(i-1)` on a large corpus.

Here is a good tutorial paper on the subject: [A Bit of Progress in Language Modeling](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/joshuago/longcombine.pdf), by Joshua Goodman.

Comment: This is also known as a Markov chain.  As I mentioned in my comment earlier, this is a common programming exercise.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The language model gives me a lot of insights!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, such things exist.

You can read about it on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammar_checker).

You can also read about some of the precision issues [here](http://faculty.washington.edu/sandeep/check/).

As far as determining which part is not right after determining the sentence has a grammar issue, that is largely impossible without knowing the author's intended meaning. Take, for example, "Over their, dead bodies" and "Over there dead bodies". Both are incorrect, and could be fixed either by adding/removing the comma or swapping their/there. However, these result in very different meanings (yes, the second one would not be a complete sentence, but it would be acceptable/understandable in context).

Spell checking works because there are a limited number of words against which you can check a word to determine if it is valid (spelled correctly). However, there are infinite sentences that can be constructed, with infinite meanings, so there is no way to correct a poorly written sentence without knowing what the meaning behind it is.

Comment: True, but the question simply asks if such things exist and if they are accurate. I think my answer and the two links cover that fairly well.

Comment: @KelvinLee and I've edited mine, I hope you find it more thorough

Comment: It also bears pointing out that a sentence or utterance can be erroneous / aberrant in many ways. "?The chicken gave a hluck" or "?I had no such hluck" are phonetically aberrant for English, but a human reader can readily form a hypothesis about their meaning. In "*The chicken gave a" the problem is clearly syntactical. In "*I has no such luck" the problem (in standard English) is morphosyntactic. In Chomsky's classical "Colorless green ideas sleep furiously" the problem is on the semantic level. Do you mean to tackle all of these?

Comment: @tripleee In my setting I can assume that there is no spelling error. The only error that I'm considering is the combination of words which really seldom occur together. For instance, the combo [so etc page hello] rarely occur together (and when you type such thing in google no useful link comes up).

Comment: A good model for sequences is the Markov model. The standard programming assignment called Dissociated text requires an implementation. You might want to read up on that. Statistics / machine learning may be prone to false positives, though (and depending on how you train it, false negatives - the old Garbage In, Garbage Out lemma).

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is a well-established library that can process natural language and extract the meanings.

Unfortunately, there's no such library. Natural language processing, as you probably can imagine, is not an easy task. It is still a very active research field. There are many algorithms and methods in understanding natural language, but to my knowledge, most of them only work well for specific applications or words of specific types.

And those libraries, such as the CMU one, seems to be still quite rudimental. It can't do what you want to do (like identifying errors in English sentence). You have to develop algorithm to do that using the tools that they provide (such as sentence parser).

If you want to learn about it check out [ai-class.com](http://ai-class.com). They have some sections that talks about processing language and words.